# node.js server: HTTP POST body is empty

Tags: node.js, http, post

I am sending info from a wi-fi connected arduino device (cc3000) to an AWS server running express/node.  I plan to eventually hook the endpoint up to SQS as a producer, but for now I am just trying to get a POST request to work.  The problem is, I am on secure shell on my AWS and the body portion is empty as I see post requests stream in.  However, the headers are present as I have sent them.  My question is, where is the data going?  Is this a formatting problem or something wrong with AWS?

Raw body of POST request (I am just using plain/text for now to see if I can get this to work):

```
POST /postdata/ HTTP/1.1
Host: *******************
User-Agent: Arduino/0.6.0
Accept: plain/text
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: plain/text

{"temperature_c": "29.80"}
```

Again, the headers are in the JSON payload, but not the "temperature" portion.

Here is the endpoint:

```
  app.post('/postdata', function (req, res) {
    Sensor_data.create(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
 });
```

The headers are present.  This is intended to write to a mongoDB.  If I do a cURL request from the command line, it writes successfully.  For example, this works:

```
curl -v *************** -d "{temp_f=28.40&relative_humidity=45.40"
```

So if the headers are there, I know I am successfully writing something to the server.  Where the heck is the data? Is this a formatting problem or something wrong with AWS?

## EDIT ########:

I double checked to make sure body-parser was set up.  I had installed the middleware in my server.js as so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

However, another issue has arisen.  I have some code in this route to help me see what is going on by logging to console.  I changed the POST request to application/json and know it is parsing because I had a small typo that I had to fix.  However, once it started parsing correctly, nothing logged to console and nothing wrote to mongoDB.  Any idea what is happening there?  If the JSON is in fact being parsed, where is it being received on the server?

Comment: Have you set up [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)? `req.body` doesn't get created automatically.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was solved by setting `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` to be initialized with `true` and creating the post request with `Accept` and `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Hope this post helps some people as I have have seen quite a few posts with people struggling with this issue

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear whether you've set up the appropriate middleware to do the parsing.  You'll find documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) - in the first example you'd need the `json` parser, and in the second you'd need `urlencoded` (although there appears to be an extra leading `{` - a typo, perhaps?).

> I am just using plain/text for now to see if I can get this to work

That's not going to work.  The json-parsing middleware decides whether to try to parse based on the content-type - if you aren't honest, it doesn't know it should try to parse.  Use `application/json` if you're going to send a JSON body.

Comment: see my edit.  I see my error in using plain/text and started writing to JSON, but now have a new issue.  Also, that was a simple typo on the cURL request and I wasn't actually sending the leading brace.

Comment: @abgordon You're posting to `/postdata/`, but the route your server expects is `/postdata`.  Depending on your express settings, that might work.